# DataGridView: How can I make the enter key add a new line instead of changing the current cell?

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

How can I make the Enter key behave in a Winforms `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` like it does in a normal Winforms `TextBox` (add a new line to the text, instead of changing the current cell)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I found out how to solve the problem.  First, create a class called `CustomDataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl` which derives from `DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl`, and override `EditingControlWantsInputKey` like this:

```
public class CustomDataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl : DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl
    {
        public override bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(
        Keys keyData, 
        bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
        {
            switch (keyData & Keys.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Enter:
                    // Don't let the DataGridView handle the Enter key.
                    return true;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            return base.EditingControlWantsInputKey(keyData, dataGridViewWantsInputKey);
    }
}
```

This stops the `DataGridView` from handing the Enter key and changing the current cell.  It does not, however, make the Enter key add a new line.  (It appears that the `DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl` has removed the functionality of the Enter key).  Therefore, we need to override `OnKeyDown` and implement the functionality ourselves, like this:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode & Keys.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Enter:
            int oldSelectionStart = this.SelectionStart;
            string currentText = this.Text;

            this.Text = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
                currentText.Substring(0, this.SelectionStart),
                Environment.NewLine,
                currentText.Substring(this.SelectionStart + this.SelectionLength));

            this.SelectionStart = oldSelectionStart + Environment.NewLine.Length;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    base.OnKeyDown(e);
}
```

Then, create a class called `CustomDataGridViewTextBoxCell` which derives from `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`, and override the `EditType` property to return the type of `CustomDataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl`.

```
public class CustomDataGridViewTextBoxCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    public override Type EditType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(CustomDataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl);
        }
    }
}
```

After you do this, you can set the `CellTemplate` property on an existing column to a `CustomDataGridViewTextBoxCell`, or you can create a class derived from `DataGridViewColumn` with `CellTemplate` preset to a `CustomDataGridViewTextBoxCell`, and you will be all set!

Comment: Hay, I like this solution. It has worked for me but there is one thing missing. How can i increase the row height of all of the cells which are on the same row as this datagridview textbox. Is this possible?. Obviously this would also need to happen on enter key press.

Comment: Apologies, the problem i was having was being caused by my autosize rows mode property being set to all cells.
 Me.EditingControlDataGridView.Rows(EditingControlRowIndex).Height += 10 worked a charm

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by setting the [DataGridViewCellStyle.WrapMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.wrapmode.aspx) property to true.  From MSDN:

> If WrapMode is False for a cell that
> contains text, the cell displays the
> text on a single line, and displays
> any embedded newline characters as box
> characters. If WrapMode is True for a
> cell that contains text, the cell
> displays newline characters as line
> breaks, but also wraps any lines that
> exceed the width of the cell.

You can set this for specific cells by accessing the Style property on a cell, or for all cells in a column by using the DefaultCellStyle for the column.

[Update]
To disable the Enter key selectively in your DataGridView, add a Message Filter to the Form containing the DataGridView as shown below:

```
private KeyMessageFilter m_filter = null;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    m_filter = new KeyMessageFilter(this); 
    Application.AddMessageFilter(m_filter);

}
```

Here is the message filter class:

```
public class KeyMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    private Form m_target = null;

    public KeyMessageFilter(Form targetForm)
    {
        m_target = targetForm;
    }

    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

    private const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;


    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            //Note this ensures Enter is only filtered if in the 
            // DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl and Shift is not also  pressed.
            if (m_target.ActiveControl != null && 
                m_target.ActiveControl is DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl && 
                (Keys)m.WParam == Keys.Enter && 
                (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) != Keys.Shift)
            {
                return true;
            }

        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Now, the Enter key is disabled when editing text and you must press the tab key to move to the next cell.  Shift + Enter still adds a newline to the text you are editing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!  Your answer fixed the issue of allowing multiple lines in the cell, but unfortunately the Enter key still changes the selected cell.

Comment: Just to make it clearer, if WrapMode is set to True the enter key will still move to the next row but you can now use Shift+Enter to embed a newline in the text. If you are happy with that behaviour the message filter is not required.

Comment: @ZachJohnson, it's working for me, but you have to be editing the text in order for the filter to prevent moving to the next cell. If you just highlight a cell and hit enter, it still moves to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Although @Zach Johnson has answered the main part of this question, his code was not working for me. After investing long time and reading different threads I realized that you have also to set some properties to get that work. So here is the full code, so you can run an example:
Define CustomDataGridViewTextBoxCell:

```
class CustomDataGridViewTextBoxCell: DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    public override Type EditType => typeof(CustomDataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl);
}
```

Then define the class `CustomDataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl`

```
class CustomDataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl : DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl
{
    public override bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(
        Keys keyData,
        bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
    {
        switch (keyData & Keys.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Enter:
                // Don't let the DataGridView handle the Enter key.
                return true;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return base.EditingControlWantsInputKey(keyData, dataGridViewWantsInputKey);
    }
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode & Keys.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Enter:
                int oldSelectionStart = this.SelectionStart;
                string currentText = this.Text;

                this.Text = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
                    currentText.Substring(0, this.SelectionStart),
                    Environment.NewLine,
                    currentText.Substring(this.SelectionStart + this.SelectionLength));

                this.SelectionStart = oldSelectionStart + Environment.NewLine.Length;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }

}
```

Then define `DataGridViewRolloverCell`:

```
public class DataGridViewRolloverCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    public override Type EditType => typeof(CustomDataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl);
}
```

After that define the class `DataGridViewCustomColumn`:

```
public class DataGridViewCustomColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public DataGridViewCustomColumn()
    {
        this.CellTemplate = new CustomDataGridViewTextBoxCell();
    }
}
```

Now if you have a `DatagridViewControl` called `dgv`, your code would look like this:

```
DataGridViewCustomColumn col =  new DataGridViewCustomColumn();
dgv.Columns.Add(col);
```

Now **important**:
You still have to set in the `DefaultCellStyle` the property `WrapText` to `true`. Do it in the designer or with this code:

```
DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle1 = DataGridViewCellStyle();
dataGridViewCellStyle1.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
dataGridViewCellStyle1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
dataGridViewCellStyle1.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
this.dgv.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
```

And do not forget to set the property `Datagridview.AutoSizeRowsMode` to `AllCells`.
Then it will work.