# multiline column in data grid view. using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Im using c# .net windows form application. i have a datagrid view. It has two columns.I need to make all the  cells on the second column as to have multiple line. i.e a multiline column. I will edit something in a cell and press enter key. the cursor should reach the next line in the same cell. It should not go to the next cell. What should i do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set the column default style like:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns[index].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

you can enter multiline by pressing SHIFT-ENTER

Otherwise you could change the cell control editor overriding dataGridView or handling EditingControlShowing event (the default control is a textbox)

EDIT:
there's almost the same question here:
[DataGridView: How can I make the enter key add a new line instead of changing the current cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030542/datagridview-how-can-i-make-the-enter-key-add-a-new-line-instead-of-changing-the)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its Working fine. But only for shift-enter.. If i press Only enter, it is going to next row. Any alternative that can allow me to use only enter key.

Comment: Take a look at the last answer in the link posted above.
It seems to work.