# Add new line in text box data grid view cells [C#]

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview, word-wrap

I have a data grid view which allows the user to enter text into a cell.I have 2 columns, one is editable, and the other is not. I want the user to be able to go to a new line in the cell while they type if they hit enter. Currently the detail view goes to the next cell. I want to stop it, stay in the current cell, and go to the next line. I set the word wrapping property  on the cell and the Auto-resize property on the grid to achieve word wrapping. I am stuck here and no key handling events for cells. How do I capture the Enter key on the specific cell ?

Comment: Please see if this works. `dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;`

Comment: This is already set as explained up there, both this property and the auto size mode properties are set. I need to be able to go to the next line i the cell when I click enter

Comment: Please check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030542/datagridview-how-can-i-make-the-enter-key-add-a-new-line-instead-of-changing-th

Comment: I dont use the standard DGV anymore, but does not `alt-enter` creates a new line in most windows applications ?

Comment: yes it does, but I do not want the user to have to click Alt or Shift. I want the user to be able to create a new line in the cell by clicking enter only

Comment: @SH7 thanks, I will flag this question as duplicate since the question link you shared has 2 accepted answers.